# Database Query not working as expected using eloquent commands for laravel

Tags: php, laravel-5.4, eloquent

I am trying to query my database that is connected to my model "Address" to find any addresses that are 'LIKE' any input into my form in the address input field. My model code is:

```
public function CheckForPrevious($verify)

{
  $matches = \App\Address::where('address', 'like', '%'.$verify.'%')

  ->get();

  foreach($matches as $match)
  {
    echo "$match";
  }



}
```

My controller code is:

```
public function show()
    {
      $address = new Address;
      $check = $_POST['address'];

      $address->CheckForPrevious($check);

      return $address;

    }
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated

Comment: You are not using `scope` correctly, take a look on the documentation https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/eloquent#local-scopes

Comment: @jogesh_pi I thought I did use scope right I have the instance used at the top of my model and I used the word scope before the name of my method. I don't know what I am missing

Comment: Here is my latest code:  `public function CheckForPrevious($verify)

   ` {
      `$matches = \App\Address::where('address', 'like', '%'.$verify.'%')

      `->get();

     ` foreach($matches as $match)
      `{
        `echo "$match";
      `}



   ` }I get a return of an empty array

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
public function show()
{
  $address = new Address();
  $check = $_POST['address'];

  $address->scopeCheckForPrevious($check);
```

}

public function scopeCheckForPrevious($verify)

```
    {
      $query = App\Address::where('address', 'like', '%'.$verify.'%')

      ->get();

      foreach($query as $match)
      {
        echo "$match";
      }



    }
```

use this

Answer (score 0):

You don't have to prefix `scope` for query scope functions

Change

```
  `$address->scopeCheckForPrevious($check)`
```

To

```
  `$address->CheckForPrevious($check)`
```

Answer (score 0):

There is no need to access model unnecessary on the scope
`$query = App\Address::where('address', 'like', '%'.$verify.'%')`

Try like this:

```
public function scopeCheckForPrevious($query, $verify)
{
    return $query->where('address', 'like', '%'.$verify.'%');
}
```

And call it with the following code:

```
$address = new Address;
$check = $_POST['address'];
dd( $address->checkForPrevious($check)->get() );
```

Comment: There are two parameters in the first Model portion of the code and there is only one in the controller